# jquery not working on my site but scripts are loading

Tags: jquery

The menu dropdown and front page slider have stopped working on my site. 
http://grmanaginggreatness.com/temp/meor/
I have no idea why. 
I see a lot of errors: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the console. But the scrips seem like they are loading.

Comment: can you post your script

Comment: ensure that jquery is loaded first before anything else :) and try to update the jquery version you are using.

Comment: You have 2 jQuery versions and a lot of included scripts in the head and body and I think some need to be in head. I suggest you have another look and keep removing scripts until you find the problem, we can't debug for you.

Comment: Do you have two versions of jQuery on your site? take a look at this: http://i.imgur.com/GDcDH8y.png. Try to use only the newest.

Comment: thanks I found the extra jquery files in the header. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

JQuery was being loaded twice so it wansn't working. I removed the extra jquery files.